# How does RPM determine newer package

Tags: rpm, upgrade, versioning, rpmbuild

I have taken the Apache httpd 2.2.3 SRPM and extracted the .spec file. From this I've replaced 2.2.3 with 2.2.14 and removed the `Serial` tag from the specfile (as `rpmbuild` complained about the Serial tag - I presume this has been deprecated). Downloaded the httpd tarball, and built (`rpmbuild`) with no errors (to my surprise).

Upon running `rpm --upgrade` <newrpms> I received an error that my new RPMs were not newer versions even though the `Version` tag is clearly later. I set the `Release`, however, to 1.

I've tried looking through Google to find out how `rpm` determines what the newest version is (no luck). From the `rpm -qi` commands I have the following for the default 2.2.3 install:

```
Name        : httpd                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.2.3                             Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 31.el5.centos                 Build Date: Thu 03 Sep 2009 10:43:06 PM BST
Install Date: Mon 26 Oct 2009 10:27:12 AM GMT      Build Host: builder16.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: httpd-2.2.3-31.el5.centos.src.rpm
Size        : 3254910                          License: Apache Software License
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Sun 20 Sep 2009 04:53:42 AM BST, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
```

From my 2.2.14 build I have:

```
Name        : httpd                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.2.14                            Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Release     : 1                             Build Date: Mon 16 Nov 2009 11:40:41 AM GMT
Install Date: Mon 16 Nov 2009 11:44:38 AM GMT      Build Host: build01.local
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: httpd-2.2.14-1.src.rpm
Size        : 5101686                          License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Signature   : (none)
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
```

So the question is: how does `rpm` determine which is the most recent RPM for upgrade purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial tag was deprecated and replaced with the epoch tag.

I don't know how the serial tag worked but version comparisons with the epoch tag have the epoch prepended to the version before the comparison.

I assume something similar was done with serial.

I'm guessing the serial value was also prepended so you are comparing versions like this:

```
<serial>-<version>-<release>
```

If the serial value was > 1 in the original I'm guessing its defaulting to 1 when not specified.

You can alwasy use `rpm --force` to force an upgrade to a specific RPM